# Detect writable static data

Tags: gcc, constants, c89

I just discovered that some parts of the code I am working on incorrectly uses writeable static data where it could/should use constant data.

Short of doing a dumb search-and-replace for "static" -> "static const", is there any way to preventing all 'static' data from being writeable, much like how constant string data can be made explicitly writeable?

I am using the GCC toolchain, development target is x86.

Comment: It's probably better to just fix your code rather than trying to use an ugly hack like this.

Comment: Well, the intention is to quickly derive which fields /actually/ have to be writeable, not to make it a build requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably writable static data in some of the libraries you use.  (Such as the standard C and C++ libraries).  Making that const would be bad.

It's probably better to go through your code and change things manually.

You can use `nm` to get a list of symbols in your `.o` files.  In the `nm` output, the first column gives the type of symbol; the letters `B`, `C`, `D`, `G` or `S` indicate writable data.  The last column gives the (mangled) variable name.  It's possible to write a little script to parse the `nm` output and look for these.

Comment: Ah, of course. Using `nm | grep -i " [BCDGS] "` gives me a list of symbols that are not in read-only sections. Thanks for seeing my actual problem and not just replying to the literal question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the better way is adding the "const" to all variables you have. You could use a "#define static static const" (note that it would break wherever you already changed it) but I don't recommend doing so (will make your code much less readable and possibly will break some things, and you won't be able to declare static functions).